# Convert working commands to VIMRC friendly mappings (ie: :%s with regex)

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, regular-expression

Is there a simple way of taking a previously issued command and converting it into a `.vimrc`-friendly keybinding?

For example, I have a simple substitution utilizing regular expressions that won't work when remapped:

```
# find all lines containing only a comment char: "#" "," ";"
# and replace with that char and --- ie: #---

:%s/^\(#\|\"\|;\)$/\1---/g<CR>
```

This works great if manually typed in.

After attempting to convert it to a binding (not a let @x persistent macro), it doesn't work:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>tb :%s/^\(#\|\"\|;\)$/\1---/g<CR><CR>
```

I've read you need to convert the `|` to `<Bar>` I believe it was, but that had zero affect.

Is there a ***vim-plugin*** or ***built-in feature*** that would allow me to convert anything in history to a keybind without manipulation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> # find all lines containing only a comment char: "#" "," ";"
> # and replace with that char and --- ie: #---
>
> :%s/^\(#\|"\|;\)$/\1---/g
> ```

The comment says the command should replace these characters:

- `#`
- `,`
- `;`

But the next command replaces these characters:

- `#`
- `"`
- `;`

Which one tells the truth?

---

> After attempting to convert it to a binding (not a let @x persistent macro), it doesn't work:

> ```
> nnoremap <silent> <leader>tb " :%s/^\(#\|"\|;\)$/\1---/g<CR>
> ```

Why is there an orphan double quote between the lhs and rhs of the mapping?

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>tb " :%s/^\(#\|"\|;\)$/\1---/g<CR>
                             ^
                             ?
```

---

> I've read you need to convert the | to  I believe it was, but that had zero affect.

This seems to work:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>tb :%s/^\(#\<bar>"\<bar>;\)$/\1---/g<CR>
```

Tip: after installing a mapping, ask Vim to print how it was installed in the mappings table:

```
:nno <leader>tb
```

If the result does not contain the exact sequence of keys you want to be executed, adapt the rhs accordingly.

---

> Is there a vim-plugin or built-in feature that would allow me to convert anything in history to a keybind without manipulation??

[Move the rhs of the mapping in a function](https://vimeo.com/15443936#t=12m56s).  The function call will still be subject to the usual mapping parsing, but whatever the function does in its body escape that parsing:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>tb :call Func()<cr>

fu Func()
    %s/^\(#\|"\|;\)$/\1---/g
endfu
```

BTW, this regex:

```
^\(#\|"\|;\)$
```

Can be simplified using a bracket expression:

```
^[#";]$
```

Also, if you have the patch [8.2.1978](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.1978), use the pseudo-key `<cmd>` to execute an Ex command:

```
nnoremap <leader>tb <cmd>call Func()<cr>
                    ^---^
```

It reduces side-effects (no `Cmdline*` events, no display on the command-line so no need of `<silent>`, ...).

If you can't use `<cmd>`, then add `<c-u>` to kill a possible range inserted in front of `:call` if you hit a count by accident (see `:h c^u`):

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>tb :<c-u>call Func()<cr>
                              ^---^
```

Comment: Ah! We got `<cmd>`! Now to remind myself why we needed it and what I need to go editing in my vim files to use it ...

Comment: Yes, that was a major change.  The credit goes to [Yegappan Lakshmanan](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/29827/yegappan-lakshmanan) for porting the feature to Vim.  There are 3 benefits: 1. it does not trigger the `Cmdline*` events; 2. it makes `<silent>` no longer necessary; 3. it makes `<c-u>` no longer necessary.

Comment: There are 2 gotchas: `<cmd>` does not make you quit visual mode, so the marks `'<` and `'>` are not set.  If your visual mapping refers to these marks, you need to make it press `<Esc>` first; otherwise, you have to play with `line('v')` and `line('.')`.  And special keys are not allowed between `<cmd>` and `<cr>`; things like `<F1>`, `<Up>`, `<Plug>(foo)`.  If you really need them (e.g. inside a `feedkeys()` call), you need to delay their processing via `<lt>`: `<F1>` = "bad", `<lt>F1>` = "good".

Comment: Thanks! That’s helpful to know

Comment: Thank you for the A+ response. The poor formatting in my question was due to attempted troubleshooting and giving up in frustration to ask a superior for help. I also removed unnecessary text from the original to simplify my question, which inevitably made things worse. You nailed it though :). Super helpful.